# How to represent mips instruction as it's hex representation

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm given a MIPS instruction:

```
top:
 lw $t1, ($t0)
 beq $s0, $0, end
 jal func
 add $s0, $s0, $t0
 addi $s0, $s0, -1
 j top
 bne $s0, $0, top
end:
func:

 sll $v0, $t1, 4
 jr $ra
```

and am told to convert each line to the "instruction in hex."  What I am having a problem with is the `jal` instruction.  I understand it is a Pseudodirect address, what I don't understand it how to write it out as asked.

Given the OPCode for a `jal` instruction is `3hex`, the first 6 bits in the J-Type instruction format would be `000011`, how do I figure out the remaining?

I understand how to complete this task for R-Type and I-Type instruction formats but cant figure this one out.

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opcode: `0000 11`

Remaining 26 bits: `Bits 2-27 of the address of label`

**Explanation**:
The machine language equivalent that you know so far is:

```
0000 11xx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

`x` represents not-known-at-this-point.

To find 32-bit Machine Language representation of `jal func`, first thing you'd need is the memory address of the label `func`. If you know the address of any of the instructions above, adding 4 to it for every instruction can give you the address of `func` label.
Lets say the address of `func` is `0x12345678` (binary: `0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000`)
This address is 32-bits while you only have 26 bits to fit in.

To deal with this, you would do two things:

1.Since this address will always be a multiple of four, the last two bits are always `00`. Therefore, we do not need to include them. Hence, our new "address" of `func` becomes: `0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 10--`

2.Now we need to fit 30-bits of `func` address in 26-bits since 6-bits are occupied by the opcode. To do this, we ignore the 4 most significant bits. Machine takes these 4-bits from the `PC`. Hence, our new "address" of `func` becomes: `---- 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 10--`

These 26-bits of the address of `func` make 32-bit Machine Language of `jal` become:

```
0000 1100 1000 1101 0001 0101 1001 1110
```

Answer (score 0):

First you take the opcode, for the top 6 bits.

```
0b000011 = 0x03
```

Then you take the address of the next instruction, let's say

```
0x00155874
```

Shift it to the right by two (or perform an integer division by 4), which makes it

```
0x0005561D
```

Padd both values to 4 bytes

```
0x3 << 26  = 0x0C000000
0x0005561D = 0x0005561D
```

Perform a bitwise-or

```
0x0C05561D
```

That's it. (I could've made a mistake somewhere, though).